# ASP Core Ajax Posting From Partials

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, .net-core, partial-views

I have a requirement to separate parts of one page into Partial Views and one of those parts contains a form to submit data. I've been playing around with this and have managed to get the form to submit without reloading the page.

However I have two problems:

- The form fields don't clear after a successful post
- If validation is broken, those validation messages don't appear when returning the result.

I'll admit i'm not too familiar with AJAX in ASP to begin with but hopefully someone can hope. Here's my code:

**Model**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MVCValidation.Models
{
    public class Thing
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string OtherValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Main View** (_Index.cshtml)

```
@model MVCValidation.Models.Thing

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Ajax Partial Test</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Edit" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_Form", Model)
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Partial View** (_Form.cshtml)

```
@model MVCValidation.Models.Thing

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Value, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Value, new {htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller** (HomeController)

```
namespace MVCValidation.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public Thing GetThing()
        {
            return new Thing(){Id = 1, OtherValue = "Other"};
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            
            return View(GetThing());
        }

        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(Thing thing)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
                return PartialView("_Form", GetThing());
            }
            
            return PartialView("_Form", thing);
        }
    }
}
```

In my _Layout view I have the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js referenced and it's loading fine. Please can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I eventually found this article: https://damienbod.com/2018/11/09/asp-net-core-mvc-ajax-form-requests-using-jquery-unobtrusive/ and saw what I was doing wrong.

I expanded my  tag to look like below:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Edit" 
   data-ajax="true" 
   data-ajax-method="POST"
   data-ajax-mode="replace"
   data-ajax-update="#result">
      <div id="result">
         @await Html.PartialAsync("_Form", Model)
      </div>
</form>
```

the PartialAsync call now takes place inside a div that ultimately will be the target for the result to populate... so it effectively replaces itself.

I also had to change the controller method to this:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(Thing thing)
{
     if(ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
     }
            
     return PartialView("_Form", thing);
}
```

This correctly returns the partial view when the model is invalid, and allows the page to be used again if it is valid.